# jQuery plugin call nested function

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Is it possible to call a nested function and use `$(this)` without having to pass `$(this)` as a param?  For example: `$(this).setValidators()` instead of `methods.setValidators($(this))`

```
(function($){
    var methods = {
        init: function(options){
            var _this = this;
            var inputs = $(":input)", _this);

            inputs.each(function(){
               methods.setValidators($(this));

               //would it be possible to do the following somehow?
               //$(this).setValidators();
            });
        },

        setValidators: function(obj){
            obj.on('click', anotherFunction);
        },

        /*
        setValidators: function(){
            $(this).on('click', anotherFunction);
        }
        */

        anotherFunction: function(){
            //do stuff
        }
    }

    $.fn.myPlugin = function(method){
        if(methods[method]){
            return(methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1)));
        }else if(typeof method === 'object' || !method){
            return(methods.init.apply(this, arguments));
        }else{
            return(false);
        }
    };
})(jQuery);


$('form').myPlugin();
```

Comment: Yes, if you don't wrap it in jQuery, and do `this.setValidators`, as it's not a DOM element to be passed to jQuery! Won't work inside the each() function though, as that's a different scope, but you have `_this` for that ! And no, `obj` and `this` will not do the same if you do it that way, as that will be the same scope issue, you still need to pass it as a parameter, or use apply().

Comment: I decided to use the apply function.  Thanks for the scope info as well.